# How to handle exceptions in Web API friendly to Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a ASP.NET Web Api application with Application Insights enabled (the latest version). The application has a custom `ExceptionFilterAttribute` attached that explicitly converts each exception to `HttpResponseMessage`. That means that no server exceptions are automatically sent to Application Insights. Profiling snapshots are also not collected.

If I send exceptions manually:

```
  var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
  telemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
```

Will this be equivalent to the default Application Insights behavior?
How do I make it to collect profiling snapshots?

Comment: Are we talking asp.net core?

Comment: No, the project targets full .NET 4.7

Comment: Well, given [the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/3cc166e3c9ec9d3f4ce77f48d3ab8c6bd6218808/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule.cs#L61) it is pretty much all you need.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! Now need to somehow force `SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor` at the same time.